# Howto get scrolling="no" on the app iframe wrapper

Tags: scroll, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe

I'm trying to remove scrollbar from my facebook app.
I tried js solution, that with the following js code and some css (overflow:hidden) on  html and body tags.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">  
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
         appId: 'My_App_Id', 
         status: true, 
         cookie: true, 
         xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(7);
       };
       (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + 
         '//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);   
       }());

      </script>
```

If i see other apps, i notice that they have scrolling property of the iframe wrapper set to "no" and this is magic for all browser.

I'm not able to set the scrolling value to "no" in any mode.

How can i do?

Thanks for any help!
Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have *Canvas Height* set to *fixed* in your app settings? Otherwise setAutoResize won’t work.

(And have you checked your browser’s error console for any messages?)